# How do I insert a custom field in a user submitted post?

Tags: posts, custom-field, images, forms

Please help! I have a form for users to submit posts, and I want them to be able to choose photos already in the media gallery based on category selected. I want to include radio buttons to choose between a few images that will attach to the post, become the featured image, or just echo out in a template file in this manner

```
    <?php $custommeta = get_post_meta($post->ID, "CategoryImage", true); ?>
```

The value of the selected image will be the image url to echo out into the custom field.

I can not figure out the code to get the custom field in the form and get the value into the custom field. I think I should use add_post_meta but I am not completely sure how to incorporate it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using the plugin [User Submitted Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-submitted-posts/) but I would take a general answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got custom fields working in the front end form linked in this post:

[How to use nonce with front end submission form?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63237/how-to-use-nonce-with-front-end-submission-form)

Here is the code used for the form page (custom page template): http://pastebin.com/YWyXL3jY

Hopefully that will be of help to you with a bit of tweaking to use image URL's instead of text as the custom field input.

I had considered using the User Submitted Post plugin too but couldn't figure out how to include custom fields with that, so ended up making the form by hand.

Comment: Thanks jo_pinkish your code definitely helped me get it semi-working :-) ! The conditional statements I added aren't working however to show images based on category selected. I'm still working on that, if I figure it out I will post here for anyone else that needs help with this same issue. I also noticed that the form validation isn't working in your code. If you figure that out, along with the nonce thing can you let me know? Thanks so much. Your help is greatly appreciated! Good luck on your project!

Comment: The value of the custom field will not save in the database? did you have this same problem?

Comment: The custom field values appear to be working fine for me, the values appear in the custom fields area on the post edit screen

Comment: Also, yes I just noticed today that the validation isn't working at all, no idea why as I used code other people had shared. I will look in to this and also I don't know if the data being passed through to the database is being sanitized and is therefore safe. This is another thing I am going to research. It's been a big learning process!

Comment: You're right, I had the wrong input names, it is showing up in the custom fields now. I will work on the validation and security as well. If I get anything I will post for you and hopefully you will do the same?

Comment: isset ($_POST['description'])
 
 to
 
$_POST['description'] != ''
Solves our problems and stops the form from posting when it should not.  got this from http://voodoopress.com/review-of-posting-from-front-end-form/

Comment: for security i wrapped my code in this... if ( empty($_POST) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['new-post'],'test_post') )
{
   echo '<div style="font-weight:bold; color:#e30000; border:1px solid #e30000; margin:10px; padding:5px;">Sorry, not verified.</div>';
   exit;
}
else
{ } then added wp_nonce_field( 'test_post','new-post' ); at the end of the form after the submit button

Comment: Hi, sorry for my delay replying, I didn't have much time spare to work on this project last week.  I've changed the - 'isset ($_POST['description']) to $_POST['description'] !=  - and that's working fine, thank you for that.  I would prefer the error message to be displayed on the same page instead of on a new page but this is something I can look in to later.

Comment: I still don't know what I'm doing with the nonce.  At the top of the form I have this: 
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] )) {

 $nonce=$_REQUEST['_wpnonce'];
 if (! wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'new-post') ) die('Well that was naughty.');

 And then at the bottom before the closing </form> tag: <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>

But I can't tell if that is actually doing anything. I didn't get a reply to my original topic unfortunately - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63237/how-to-use-nonce-with-front-end-submission-form

Comment: Oh and another thing (sorry for multiple posts!) I realised wp_insert_post does handle sanitizing - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post#Description - so I assume that means the form is fairly safe in terms of people submitting malicious data.